# FBSession checkThreadAffinity

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have used facebook authentication via facebook's SDK. If fbaccount is available then it's working fine but in the absent of fbaccount it crashes with this error:

> FBSession checkThreadAffinity

I am using [this code for the auth process](http://pastebin.com/GxDT8Epj)

Please check what I am doing wrong in above code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
The problem was that I was trying to call methods om the `[FBSession activeSession]` or any `FBSession` static method from another thread. My conclusion is that the `FBSession` object is not thread safe.

I cannot find any issue in your code. However, check when you first call the `FBSession` object, is it called from the main thread? If its not, that could be the cause.